# JibJab like Face Replacement

Tags: opencv, video, face

I was trying a sample with face detection and replacement, but I want to do something smooth like how jibjab.com does.

When I think about this, the videos should have been pre-processed and the faces co-ordinates have to be marked.

I tried this sample using OpenCv to automatically replaces a detected face with a given image.

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if frame is None:
    break
  result_image = frame.copy()

  faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.1, 2, 0|cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, (30, 30))

  if len(faces) != 0:

    for f in faces:
      x, y, w, h = [ v for v in f ]
      #resize image to the face size in the video
      img = cv2.resize(replace_face, (w, h))
      cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,255,0), 5)
      sub_face = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
      result_image[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1]] = img
```

But the image replacement is not smooth as on in JibJab obviously it is replaced frame by frame.

How would I go about doing this? If I need to process each video manually for capturing face coordinates and then replace with an image what technologies or tools should I be using?

Comment: What do you mean by not smooth? Can you attach current output and expected output ?

Comment: expected output is this https://www.jibjab.com/view/template/despacito

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the haar-based face detector for this the way you're using it. What you can do is to use [dlib's face landmark detector](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/04/02/faster-facial-landmark-detector-with-dlib/) to detect the eyes and mouth, then find the homography that transforms the given face to the face in the video. Probably you need to also apply a smoothing filter, like an [alpha beta filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_beta_filter) so the face doesn't appear jittery.